# How shift UISearch bar to top of screen on click

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, uisearchbar

I am trying to model the UX for search as follows:

[image]

[image]

How can I shift the search bar to the top of the screen and darken the screen as shown in the screenshots above?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably want to look into using a [`UISearchDisplayController`](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISearchDisplayController_Class/Reference/Reference.html). Doing so will automatically give you this functionality.